# Postman Object hasOwnProperty Tests

Tags: json, objeto, postman

Estoy tratando de evaluar un JSON, para poder saber si las propiedades son correctas, tengo el siguiente código:

```
var data = JSON.parse(responseBody);

Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
 if(data.hasOwnProperty(key)){
   console.log("Tiene todas las Propiedades");
 }
});
```

El problema que tengo es que, la respuesta se me muestra "n" veces, ¿cómo puedo hacer que me la muestre solo una vez después de evaluar que las propiedades existen?

Comment: Tu código no tiene sentido. Construyes un `array` con las propiedades del objeto `data` y luego recorres ese `array` y verificas que el objeto tiene cada propiedad listada. ¿Entiendes que esto nunca evaluará a `false` en el condicional que utilizas?. Por otro lado, la respuesta (el `console.log()` que haces) se muestra precisamente por cada elemento del `array` que estás recorriendo. La verdad que no termino de entender lo que pretendes hacer. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, gracias por leer mi pregunta, al final me lograron ayudar en StackOverFlow en inglés:

```
var data = JSON.parse(responseBody);

let hasProperties = true;

Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
 if!(data.hasOwnProperty(key)){
   hasProperties = false;
 }
});

if (hasProperties) {
   console.log("Have all properties");
}
```

La idea era, evaluar si las propiedades que llegan al Objeto son las correctas y que tengan esas propiedades tal cuales. Dejo el código por si alguien en un futuro cercano lo llegara a necesitar.